# converting .obj file into .js with the help of convert_obj_three.py provided by three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl, 3dsmax, .obj

Ok, i exported a file from 3ds max into .obj format. From what I have know, its best to first convert .max file into .obj then to .js for the use of three.js to render the model in the browser.

But I am stuck in the second part of conversion. (.max -> .obj -> .js). I have managed to export from .max to .obj. But don't know how to convert .obj into .js file. I have downloaded the convert_obj_three.py from three.js converters. Also I have downloaded 2.5.4 python. But don't have a clue for what I have to do next.

Answer (score 2):

go to Command Prompt(run->cmd)

to run the py file do this:

```
C:\Python26\python.exe C:\myFolder\whatever.py -i filename -o outputname
```

Thats it...I have python 2.6 so it resides in Python26 folder...